# Indexes with included columns or composite indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Looking at the missing index DMVs on SQLServer it suggests I add the following index:

`CREATE INDEX [IXFoo] ON [a].[b].[MyTable] ([BarFlag]) INCLUDE ([BazID])`

There's two things that confuse me.

- `[BarFlag]` is a bit field. Hardly highly selective, why put an index on a bit field?
- Why not use a composite index in this case.: `CREATE INDEX [IXFoo] ON [a].[b].[MyTable] ([BarFlag],[BazID])`

I guess I'm not understanding the `INCLUDE` keyword properly. I've looked at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) for an explanation but I'm still unclear.

Can someone explain why this index is suggested over a composite and explain the `INCLUDE` keyword to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference is this:

- if you create a composite index on `(BarFlag, BazID)`, then your index will contain both values on all levels of the index b-tree; this means, the query analyzer will also have the chance to use both values when making decisions, and this can support queries that specify both columns in a WHERE clause
- if you create an index on `(BarFlag)` and only include `(BazID)`, then your index will contain only `BarFlag` values on all levels of the index b-tree, and only on the leaf level, the "last" level, there will also be the values of `BazID` included. The `BazID` values cannot be used in selecting the data - they're just present at the index leaf level for lookup.

Just for an INT and a BIT that isn't much of a concern, but if you're dealing with a `VARCHAR(2000)` column, you **cannot** add that to the actual index (max. is 900 byte per entry) - but you **can** include it.

Having a column included in an index can be useful if you select for these two values - then if SQL Server finds a match for `BarFlag`, it can look up the corresponding `BazID` value in the leaf-level node of the index itself and it can save itself a trip back to the actual data page (a "bookmark lookup") to go grab that value from the data pages. This can be a massive boost for performance

And you're right - having an index just on `BarFlag` (BIT) really doesn't make sense - then again, that DMV only suggests indices  - you're not supposed to blindly follow all its recommendations - you still need to think and consider if those are good recommendations (or not).

Answer (score 3):

The `INCLUDE` keyword just means that the value of the included columns should be stored in the index itself so that for queries like the following:

```
SELECT BazID FROM MyTable WHERE BarFlag = @SomeValue
```

It isn't necessary to do an additional lookup on the table itself in order to find the value of `BazID` after doing an index seek.